# Install datadog agent for AWS ECS metrices directly on host instance

Tags: containers, amazon-ecs, monitoring, datadog

Is it possible to collect AWS ECS container level metrices by installing datadog agent directly on the host instances and not as a daemon service across the cluster ?

I have not got any solution to do so yet. I have tried installing datadog as daemon serevice on aws ecs but it does not let me collect host level metrices.